# Database count method stopping ajax calls in rspec, capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, let

I'm trying to test for an AJAX response in my ruby on rails app. A user is supposed to be able to go on the website, submit an email, get a message, and the server is supposed to create a new DemoRequest object and send out an email using ActionMailer. To do this, I'm using rpsec capybara and selenium as my webdriver. I first tried using

```
expect { click_button submit }.to change(DemoRequest, :count).by(1)
```

but that didn't work, because I read that having it be an Ajax request messed up the timing. To get around that limitation, I'm trying to use let! to declare a variable that's equal to DemoRequest.count, and then seeing if that increased after. However, that seems to make the Ajax requests either not being sent or not being a response. If I use let!, even the messages don't show up. Here's the code.

```
before { Capybara.current_driver = :selenium }
let!(:numberDemoRequest) {DemoRequest.count}
it "should be cool" do
  visit '/index.html'
  fill_in "demo_email", with: valid_address
  click_button 'Notify me' 
  should have_content('Email ' + valid_address.downcase + ' saved! We\'ll let you know when beta is ready to begin.') 
end
specify { expect(DemoRequest.count).to eq numberDemoRequest + 1}
```

let! doesn't work. Same thing if I try to set a `numberDemoRequest = DemoRequest.count` somewhere in the block. If I change it to let, then it "works" in the sense that the Ajax calls are sent and received correctly, but the tests fail because `numberDemoRequest` isn't evaluated until the very end. So my questions are:

1. Why is calling DemoRequest.count apparently messing up the ajax call?
2. How do I actually test to see that new DemoRequest objects are created?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have transactional fixtures turned on (or are you using database cleaner with the strategy set to transaction)?

Comment: No fixtures, using database cleaner.